# Excel Interop VSTO Chart: Retrieve the chart Data Range?

Tags: vsto, excel-interop

I know how to set the range containing the Data (chart.SetSourceData(...))

But how can I retrieve the Chart Data range?
Does a range = chart.GetDataSource() exists ??

I cannot find it.

Help welcome,

Jean-Marie

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a direct way. My best suggestion is to go over the series of the chart and check the Values and XValues of the series.

```
foreach (Series series in chart.SeriesCollection()){
   Range values = series.Values;
   Range xvalues = series.XValues;
}
```

You can then join all the ranges together and get the source data of the chart.